# Visual Studio debug information not being re-generated after code change

Tags: visual-studio

I'm having a weird problem in Visual Studio 2008. Every once in a while, after adding/removing some members of a class, when examining the contents of an object of that class in the watch window the changes to that class don't appear to have been recognized. Instead, all of the old members are there, including anything that was removed, and nothing new shows up. Furthermore, the data of the members it shows is messed up, likely because the memory layout of the object has changed.

I've been using Visual Studio 2008 for years and encountered this problem for the first time about a month ago. Re-installing the program did the trick, but now it's cropped up again.

I've tried a full rebuild, deleting the .pdb file, deleting the .ncb file, deleting the .exe, the .obj files, the .sln file, etc. Nothing seems to solve it. Has anyone come across something like this before?

Thanks!

*UPDATE*

I realized it may not have been obvious from the initial post, so I wanted to clarify that the code behaves correctly, it's just the debugging information that's wrong.

*UPDATE Number 2*

Just tried downloading Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition, but it has the same problem.

Comment: Can it be that you renamed an assembly? I was encountering something similar where VS showed information from the old assembly but not the new one. Was quite painful to find all the old assemblies which were scattered over the whole harddrive.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I don't even know how to rename assemblies. Is there something in particular I should be looking for?

Answer (score 1):

So finally I was able to fix this just to moving around some variables in the header file. I'm quite sure I tried this the last time I encountered this problem, but to no avail then. This time, for whatever reason, it seemed to work. Thanks Joachim for your time in trying to help!